# Display already hidden table cells in IE with CSS

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html-table, css-tables

IE 7 does not display the initially hidden table cells (class="c") when class of the containing div is changed to "b", where "display:none" rule is removed. However, it should as it does for the row (class="r"). Other browsers behave properly. Seems like an IE bug. Did anyone came across this issue before? Any solutions?

```
<html>
<head><style type="text/css">
.a .c { display: none; }
.a .r { display: none; }
.b .c { display: block; } /*Edited after comments, still not working*/
.b .r { display: block; } /*Edited after comments, still not working*/
</style></head><body>
<div class="a">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>11</td>
            <td class="c">12</td>
            <td>13</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>21</td>
            <td class="c">22</td>
            <td>23</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="r">
            <td>31</td>
            <td class="c">32</td>
            <td>33</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div><button onclick="document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].className = 'b'">Change class</button></body></html>
```

PS: I am trying to find a CSS only solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `display: table-cell;` or `display: table-row;` in your separate class, for your `<td>` and `<tr>` tags respectively.

This won't work in IE6/7, so there are 2 other alternatives:

1. Nest a `<span>` tag and use the `display: (none|block)` property in CSS on this instead.
2. Use `text-indent: (-9999em|0)` to push the text off screen.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. IE 7 doesn't support them neither. I've omitted them for cross browser compatibility, so that I don't have to check to assign 'block' (for IE) or 'table-cell' (for others) and let browsers assign whatever proper value necessary. 

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Out of curiosity, try using IDs instead of classes for the div's identifier.

Comment: Also, using: <td><span class="c">32</span></td> as a workaround. Superfluous code, but cross browser.

Comment: Wrapping content with a span workaround "looks" like working when table uses collapsed borders. Nice. But this requires some changes to my application which I would rather do as a last resort if a CSS only solution won't be found. Thanks again. (Using ID didn't make any difference.)

Comment: Given that display is the only proper way of making things hide or show (though you could use `text-indent: -9999em` to hide stuff, `0em` to show) I think using a span might be your best bet at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

This is the kind of browser inconsistancy that jQuery is great for.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryui.com/latest/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('td.c').hide();
        $('tr.r').hide();

        $('button').click(function(){
            $('td.c').show();
            $('tr.r').show();
        });
    });
</script>
```

And change your button to

```
<button>Change class</button>
```

Comment: I agree; you can also use it to remove class a and add b if that's what the OP wants.

Comment: The table must be rendered with those columns hidden first. CSS is also working when the table is rendered with those columns visible on document load and then toggled. I am actually able do this with javascript modifying the css rules (setup slightly different than those in this sample). However, a pure CSS solution would be much simpler and perfect for my case. I only need to take care of IE for this mehtod. Thanks.

Comment: Like I said, just remove class a and add class b, no changes to your css and html needed

Comment: @jeroen, without script (a requirement) how will the rows and cells be made hidden initially if the classes a and b are removed? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Ah, I see your point. But classes a and b are required. They are used to indicate the state of filter active (like, a = show negative values, b = show positive values).

Comment: Code could (and should) be simplified to: `$('.c, .r').hide();` and `$('.c, .r').show()` where you're repeating twice.

Answer (score 0):

Your b classes both need `display: block;` FWIW `display: table-cell`, and `display: table-row` should be used to make non table elements behave like tables. Also I'm not sure if `table-cell` and `table-row` are supported consistently across browsers.

Edit: I'm not sure if a pure CSS solution will be possible here. Generally I use javascript to reset the display property to "" (empty string). This allows each browser to do what it thinks is right to get the table elements to display again. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: I've edited the sample code to prevent further confusion. However, still doesn't work. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the validity, but if you just want to make it work, try to replace display: block; with display: ''; It's worked for me.